# MATLAB - imwrite error in certain folders

Tags: matlab, recording

this is my first question so I hope I am writing in the right place.

I am currently working with a Grasshopper3 camera, model: GS3-U3-50S5M-C from Point Grey Research connected to MATLAB.
I am recording a lot of frames at a time in grayscale and in order to avoid filling up my memory I would like to move some of the frames to my disk as stacked TIFFs during the recordings. The stacked TIFF format is needed for other programs used.

I am doing this by moving the recorded frames from the camera to the workspace using *getdata*. This creates a *4-D uint8* object containing height, width, color plane and frame number of the frames. In order to save the frames as a stacked TIFF I use a *for* loop with *imwrite* to save one frame at a time as shown below. However when I do this I most often get the error:

*Error using imwrite (line 454) Unable to open file "C:\Users\My_User\Desktop\CraneStuff3\Name.tif" for writing.  You might not have write permission.*

When this happens MATLAB has typically saved some of the frames, e.g. if I have recorded 500 frames it might save 300 before giving me the error. Sometimes it manages to save every frame with no error, sometimes it only saves 30 frames before failing. I do not understand how it can save some frames and then claim that it cannot open the file for writing.

I have noticed, however, that if I instead save the file in *"C:\Users\My_User\Documents\MATLAB"* it seems to never give any error and save every frame as wanted.

Does anyone know why this is the case or how I can fix my problem? 
I have included my code below here.

Note: I tried saving the frames as a .mat-file. To do this I had to use version '-v7.3' in *save*.

Thank you advance.

```
% Connect to camera:
vid = videoinput('pointgrey',1,'F7_Mono8_2448x2048_Mode0');
vid.TriggerRepeat = 100;
vid.FrameGrabInterval = 1;

% Make a recording:
start(vid)
pause(50)
stop(vid)

% Get data from camera to workspace:
data = getdata(vid,vid.FramesAvailable);

% Save data to disk one image at a time:
num = size(data);
output_name = fullfile('C:\Users\My_User\Desktop\CraneStuff3', ['Name' '.tif']);
for k = 1:num(4)
    imwrite(data(:,:,:,k),output_name,'WriteMode','append');
end
```

Comment: Perhaps the file sizes are too big because of you triying to run the code several times? Depending on OS/hard drive partition mode you can not have  arbitrarily large file sizes, and if you are continuously appending...

Comment: I think the size of the file does play a role since the error appears more frequently for larger files. It did not seem to be a problem, however, when I was saving in the ...\Documents\MATLAB folder, the largest file I tried was 2.3GB, though.

Comment: If you have an option, just do not write files that are massive. Better divide it into frames. I work often with datasets that are 2000x2000x3000 and what everyone does is save 3000 single frame images.

Comment: Perhaps that is the way to do it, I will give it try.
Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you both for your replies, they are much appreciated.
I have managed to find another topic on this which led to the solution of my problem, Microsoft Explorer was the one causing trouble.
http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/11/09/the-mystery-of-the-failing-tiff-append-loop/

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution is to try saving each of the frames separately into a tiff file.

If you save a .mat file, better use [`savefast`](https://github.com/djoshea/matlab-utils/blob/master/saving/savefast.m)

Comment: You may want to clarify and expand on your answer a bit here.